Check JS compiled bundle size in React app
I am looking for a way to check how much JS my app is loading. I was pretty sure I can do it in the Network-->JS tab in Chrome, but every time I refresh the page the numbers are completely different:

Similar situation when i console.log performance.memory:

What am I doing wrong?
The motivation for this is to check how the bundle changes if I optimize the app with some things.

"every time I refresh the page the numbers are completely different" – do you have "Disable cache" enabled? Also, what's your actual end goal? There are tools that can analyze a bundle size (e.g. I've written https://akx.github.io/webpack-xray/ for Webpack), but that's not telling you e.g. how much your browser needs to load on initial page load.

My actual end goal is: Before my app loaded XXX of JS, now after updates it loads YYY

Not sure if this helps but can comparing the JS bundle size while between different builds of the app can give you an idea of that?
